# accessing aspx page control id from a class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods, controls

I have a class which has a method, and a web page (default.aspx) with textboxes buttons etc. They both are in the same namespace.

I need to access to default.aspx' s control ID's (for example a textbox ID) from the class method. Because I need to get the values from default.aspx controls to do some checks with the database, and it needs to be done in the class method.

have any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better/easier to use the ASP.Net `Page` model (postback, etc) to do such? If you have some other project/assembly that encapsulates common methods/unit of work/etc. then you can invoke it from there (and gain separation of concerns)?

Comment: You're right it would. I just wonder why i can't call them from class? the class is in the same namespace with the webform